# check onItemclick(Array adapter) by value not by position

Tags: java, android

i know how to onItemClick works with position, but is it possible by the list value??
Fog eg. we have list of custom Array list(arraylist):

```
arraylist(new info("a","1"));
arraylist(new info("b","2"));
arraylist(new info("c","3"));
```

and in info.class:

```
String letter,number;
info(String t1,String t2){
letter=t1;
number=t2;
}
```

customAdapter(u know this well :)..)

Now,
i know how to use condition with position of list:
(under onItemclick function)

```
switch(position){
case 0:blah blah...
case 1:blah blah...
case 2:blah blah..
}
```

but is there a way to check the condition with the value..like this:

```
if(letter==a)
blah blah..
if(letter==b)
blah blah..
```

plse help.. sorry if it confuse you..but i am weak at explaining..

Comment: First get info object from ArrayList then check condition for value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `switch()`

`arraylist.get(position)` : get Info object

`arraylist.get(position).letter` : get the value of `letter`

```
switch(arraylist.get(position).letter){
  case "a":
  break;
  case "b":
  break;
  case "c":
  break;
}
```

or

```
String value =arraylist.get(position).letter;
if (value.equals("a")){}
else if(value.equals("b")){}
else if(value.equals("c")){}
```

Comment: thanks..but since i could not access variable directly i uset method to get variable value: public String getLetter(){return letter;}

Comment: @wangz i am glad  that i could help and yeahhh you've done it  :) happy coding